# Creating Meta-boxes

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

Found a function which add to my admin panel one meta-box. It's looks nice, but not enough.
I need at least ten custom fields. How to create them? 
The questoins looks stupid, because my knowledge of php are minimal, so do not judge strictly ;). I will be grateful for the solution of this problem or an explanation of how it should work.

```
function myplugin_add_meta_box() {
 $screens = array( 'post', 'page' );
  foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {
   add_meta_box(
   'myplugin_sectionid',
   __( 'My Post Section Title', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
   'myplugin_meta_box_callback',
   $screen
  );
 }
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_meta_box' );
/**
* Prints the box content.
* 
* @param WP_Post $post The object for the current post/page.
*/
function myplugin_meta_box_callback( $post ) {

wp_nonce_field( 'myplugin_meta_box', 'myplugin_meta_box_nonce' );
$value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta_value_key', true );

echo '<label for="myplugin_new_field">';
_e( 'Description for this field', 'myplugin_textdomain' );
echo '</label> ';
echo '<input type="text" id="myplugin_new_field" name="myplugin_new_field" value="' .    esc_attr( $value ) . '" size="25" />';
}
/**
* When the post is saved, saves our custom data.
*
* @param int $post_id The ID of the post being saved.
*/
function myplugin_save_meta_box_data( $post_id ) {
if ( ! isset( $_POST['myplugin_meta_box_nonce'] ) ) {
return;
}
if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['myplugin_meta_box_nonce'], 'myplugin_meta_box' ) ) {
return;
}
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
return;
}
if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
  return;
}
} else {
if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
  return;
}
}
if ( ! isset( $_POST['myplugin_new_field'] ) ) {
return;
}
$my_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['myplugin_new_field'] );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_meta_value_key', $my_data );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'myplugin_save_meta_box_data' );
```

Comment: Eva, [so] and [wordpress.se] *are **full*** of examples, I've wrote lots answers like this. Just research for `add_meta_box` + `save_post`

Comment: @brasofilo trying to find some solution of it, but seems php makes me crazy

Answer (score 1):

If your knowledge of PHP is quite low, there are some great plugins that allow you to do this easily.

If you have a lot of fields to add, I usually find it easier to use the following plugin as ordering fields and pulling them out in themes is a lot easier than doing it manually.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Comment: I can't made a code by my self but i understend it, don't want to overload the resource by plugins

Comment: If you can't code it yourself I really would suggest going down the plugin road. You shouldn't notice any speed differences from one plugin. That said if you're set on doing it yourself I can only suggest reading up the documentation on meta boxes http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box or googling for `multiple meta box wordpress` and reading one of the many tutorials.